# numpy matrix minimum applied to second array

Tags: python, numpy

I really want to avoid looping for this simple problem...

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,1,2], [7,4,9,1]])
y = np.array([[2,5,6,7], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]])
print(x)
[[1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 1 2]
 [7 4 9 1]]

maxidx = np.argmax(x, axis=0)
print(maxidx)
[2 1 2 0]
```

So far so good. Now all I want it the entries in the y array for these indices. Since I get the index for each column only, I am not sure how to apply this correctly without looping or creating a list...thanks!

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: The output should be [1 2 3 7]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [multidimensional-indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays):

```
>>> indices = np.argmax(x, axis=0)
>>> y[indices, np.arange(x.shape[1])]
array([1, 2, 3, 7])
```